# Closing a moviepy VideoFileClip with Pygame events

Tags: python, pygame, moviepy

I'm trying to create a python program that loops the same clip until the user presses the *esc* key or closes the window.
I saw a question here that advised using **moviepy** with **pygame**, but the problem is when I am running a **VideoFileClip preview**, `pygame.event.get()` doesn't seem to write events like it is supposed to.
When I press the exit button, the program just restarts the clip and doesn't even enter the `for event in pygame.event.get():` loop at line 22. Any help is appreciated

```
from moviepy.editor import *
import pygame
import os

pygame.init()

clip = VideoFileClip('videos/nightRide.mp4')

pygame.display.set_caption("Melancholic Cat")

catImage = pygame.image.load("images/cat.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(catImage)

run = True
while run:
    
    clip.preview()
    pygame.display.init()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():  
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            run = False  

    if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        run = False

pygame.display.quit()
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Remove [`pygame.display.init()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.init) from the loop, but add [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

Comment: @Rabbid76 I replaced ```pygame.display.init()``` with ```pygame.display.flip()``` and it still won't close